# Document Wise Summary in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a cron in my application which stores application data in the following format. one document per day. Following is one sample document of a day.

```
{
    timestamp: "2018-02-01",
    data: [
        {
            project_name: "ABC",
            engineer: "tom"
            line_of_code: 100,
            testcases: 10
        },
        {
            project_name: "DEF",
            engineer: "tom",
            line_of_code: 300,
            testcases: 3
        },
        {
            project_name: "DEF",
            engineer: "dick",
            line_of_code: 100,
            testcases: 10
        },
        {
            project_name: "GHI",
            engineer: "dick",
            line_of_code: 10,
            testcases: 10
        },
        {
            project_name: "JKL",
            engineer: "harry",
            line_of_code: 110,
            testcases: 14
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to draw some plot and I need the daily summary in the following fashion.

```
[
    {
        timestamp: "2018-03-01",
        "tom": {
            "total_line_of_code": XXXX,
            "total_testcases": YYYY
        },
        "dick": {
            "total_line_of_code": XXXX,
            "total_testcases": YYYY
        },
        "harry": {
            "total_line_of_code": XXXX,
            "total_testcases": YYYY
        }
    },
    {
        timestamp: "2018-03-02",
        "tom": {
            "total_line_of_code": XXXX,
            "total_testcases": YYYY
        },
        "dick": {
            "total_line_of_code": XXXX,
            "total_testcases": YYYY
        },
        "harry": {
            "total_line_of_code": XXXX,
            "total_testcases": YYYY
        }
    }
]
```

Is it possible to write a similar query in mongodb which can consolidate on a daily basis and return an array where each object represents one day summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                timestamp: "$timestamp",
                engineer: "$data.engineer"
            },
            lines_of_code: { $sum: "$data.line_of_code" },
            testcases: { $sum: "$data.testcases" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.timestamp",
            items: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.engineer",
                    v: {
                         total_line_of_code: "$lines_of_code",
                         total_testcases: "$testcases"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            timestamp: "$_id",
            data: {
                $arrayToObject: "$items"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$data" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: 0
        }
    }
])
```

To transform your documents into a format where `engineer` field is used as a key you need to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) - that's why we're transforming to properties `v` and `k`. Before that you need to use `$unwind` and then group by person per day to get total numbers.